# Water seaps in from concrete driveway under brick wall into concrete sunroom

Tags: waterproofing

My house was built in 1978, I bought it three years ago.

It has a step down concrete slab sun room. The sun room has brick walls and  joins my concrete driveway.

I have caulked the joint area where the brick wall separates the driveway from the sun room but i am still getting water leaking from outside in.

I was told i need a french drain.

Are there any alternative solutions ?

Comment: Pictures would be a huge help here. We need to see the interface between the brick wall and the slab/driveway.

Comment: the word is `seeps`

Comment: reduce the water that even gets to the joint; more/cleaner/better gutters would be the place to start.